# How to integrate scalar field over quarter torus? Infinite series does not converge.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, geometry, convergence-divergence, physics

This seems to be physics question, but the problem just concerns math.

---

## Preface

If one wants to calculate the permeance $P$ of a rectangular bar:

[image]

it is an easy task:

$$P = \frac{\mu a b}{L} ~~~~ \rightarrow ~~~~  P\propto ab  ~~~~and~~~~  P\propto\frac{1}{L}$$

where $\mu$ is the material constant. (Permeability)

---

## Question

But my geometry is a **torus with just a quarter of its circular cross section** and the field $V$ **passes through it parallel to the circumference** of the (full) cross section:

[image]

How can I calculate the permeance of this geometry, when there are the same proportional relations as above?

---

## Attempted solution

I divide my geometry in $N$ hollow toruses with constant wall thickness $\Delta R$ and medium length element $\Delta L$, so the field passes an area of $\Delta A$:

[image]

A little piece of the radius $R$ is $\Delta R = \frac{d}{N}$. Now one can calculate:

$$\Delta P_{n} = \frac{\mu \Delta A_n}{\Delta L_n} $$

with
$$ \Delta A_n = \pi \bigg( (R+(n+1) \Delta R)^2-(R+n \Delta R)^2\bigg) $$
(Consider the full torus circumference, not just a quarter as displayed)

and
$$ \Delta L_n = \frac{\pi}{2} (2n+1) \frac{\Delta R}{2} $$
(but quarter cross section!)

follows:

$$P = \sum^{N-1}_{n=0} \Delta P_{n} = \mu\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}  \frac{\pi(2R\Delta R+(2n+1)(\Delta R)^2)}{\frac{\pi}{2}(2n+1)(\frac{\Delta R}{2})}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$

$$= 4\mu\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}  \frac{2r\Delta R+(2n+1)(\Delta R)^2}{(2n+1)(\Delta R)} $$

$$= 4\mu\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}  \Bigg( \frac{2R}{(2n+1)} + \Delta R \Bigg)~~~~~~~~~~ $$

$$= 4\mu \Bigg( d + 2R \sum^{N-1}_{n=0}   \frac{1}{(2n+1)} \Bigg)~~~~~~~~~~ $$

**And this series does not converge for $N\rightarrow\infty$.** Which is physically seen not possible, so there must be a problem with the math. Do you see what I'm missing?

Comment: Awesome pictures.  What did you use to make them?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Inkscape (open source) is great for creating these sorts of graphics.

Comment: @AntonioVargas ... or Adobe Illustrator

Comment: How do you get $\Delta L_n$?

Comment: @Shine: Consider the origin of $d$ as the origin of the cross section coordinate system, which is equal to $R$. Now you have to calculate $(2n+1)$ times the half of $\Delta R$ (basically the height of every $\Delta A_n$) to get the medium circumference of $\Delta A_n$. But then just a quarter ($\pi/2$) of the circumference should be considered for the path length $\Delta L_n$.

Comment: What I note is that, as it stands, you'll run into the same problem if you did a wedge of angle $\theta$ rather than $\pi/2$ specifically. In particular, it would seem to hold over to a narrow wedge $\delta \theta$; that's strange, since one can compute $P\sim \mu b/(\delta \theta)$. (The divergence in that expression having nothing to do with the radial coordinate unlike your diverent series.)

Comment: @Semiclassical and what is your conclusion? How would you calculate one wedge?

Comment: I calculated $P$ from your formula at top: a wedge in that case is essentially just rectangular bar with $L\approx a \delta \theta$ and cross-section $a b$. (I probably should've said $P\approx \mu/\delta\theta$.) And my point is that if you focus on that case, you'll probably find the problem since it's not the angular thickness which is creating your divergence.